# Fluid Boundary layer in presence of a postive heat gradient

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions

I was wondering how a boundary layer would be dissipative of momentum if it was under the influence of a positive heat gradient.

I understand that the reason that we don't see the boundary pressure equal the stagnation pressure is that the boundary is dissipative (so excess pressure above static pressure is "dumped" thru the pipe wall to the surroundings.)

If this heat gradient was reversed I could see that we would have an additional internal gradient from a boundary quasi stagnation pressure to the lower static pressure in the moving fluid.

This gradient could be resolved by adding energy to the flowing fluid.

Should this mean that we would lose less momentum from the flow ?

[image: Thermal Gradient opposing momentum gradient]

Answer (score 0):

"...boundary is dissipative...". Not just boundary, but the entire fluid is dissipative because of viscosity. However dissipation may be dominant in regions close to boundary.

It is incorrect to say "...excess pressure above static pressure is "dumped" thru the pipe wall to the surroundings...". Momentum is converted into heat within the fluid due to viscous action, and if the conditions are right (i.e. if the mean temperature gradient is in the right direction) this may get dumped out of the fluid into the ambient.

By "heat gradient" I suppose you mean temperature gradient. If the temperature gradient is such that temperature increases in the direction of gravity (called unstable stratification) then it is true that it can inject momentum into the fluid, causing convection. Source of this momentum (or kinetic energy of motion) is essentially potential energy within the fluid by virtue of having created a top-heavy configuration. However if temperature gradient is such that it decreases along the direction of gravity (called stable stratification), it does not cause any motion, and in fact may end up damping what motion is already there.

However momentum (or kinetic energy) of fluid that was lost to viscous dissipation must be considered lost. Any motion that may be caused by unstable stratification of fluid is a separate matter, and cannot be said to reverse that momentum loss in any useful sense. It is more appropriate to say that unstable stratification injects new momentum into the fluid (if the conditions are right, i.e. small temperature gradients may not achieve much). This is so because heating appropriately can inject momentum into static fluid, where there was no dissipation to begin with.